# Let $f:[0;1]\to\mathbb R$ be continiously differentiable

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $f:[0;1]\to\mathbb R$ be continiously differentiable  and $ f(0)=0$.

Prove that $\int\limits_0^1 |f(x)|^2\, dx\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^1 |f'(x)|^2\, dx.$

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative path**

Here is an alternative to the answer by @robjohn, using Cauchy--Schwarz inequality directly, avoiding the so-called Iverson brackets. Then interval monotonicity is used in the integral.

First, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt.
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx & = \int_0^1\biggl(\int_0^x 1\cdot f'(t)\,dt\biggr)^2\,dx\\
&\leq\int_0^1\biggl(\int_0^x 1^2\,dt\int_0^x f'(t)^2\,dt\biggr)\,dx\\
&\leq\int_0^1\biggl(x\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,dt\biggr)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1x\,dx\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f'(t)^2\,dt.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Completely alternative path**

Not to make this answer just a modification of the one by @robjohn, let us show that the optimal constant is not $1/2$, but in fact,
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx\leq\frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_0^1 f'(x)^2\,dx.
$$
This can be seen by studying the eigenvalue problem
$$
-u''(x)=\lambda u(x),\quad u(0)=0,\quad u'(1)=0,
$$
which has the lowest eigenvalue $\lambda=\pi^2/4$. Equality holds for all scalar multiples of the corresponding eigenfunction $u(x)=\sin(\pi x/2)$.

Comment: I can show the optimal constant, but my method uses the calculus of variations. Do you have a way that doesn't use the calculus of variations?

Comment: Probably it will work using Fourier series and Parseval as well. My argument with the eigenvalue is essentially variational.

Comment: Do you really want the restriction $u'(0)=0$? $\sin(\pi x/2)$ does not satisfy that constraint.

Comment: Thank you. That was a misprint. I think it should be correct now.

Comment: Now I'm more curious. The problem is solvable without that constraint. Why have that constraint?

Comment: It comes naturally when you are minimizing the corresponding quadratic form. Typically one says that one has a "free condition", i.e. the trial functions that you minimize over do not necessarily satisfy any particular boundary condition. This leads to a Neumann boundary condition. I think this is explained well in a rather elementary way in section 11.3 in Strauss book on Partial differential equations. If you want a more detailed discussion of different self-adjoint extensions I suggest to read Rudin's Functional analysis or the book by Akhiezer--Glazman.

Answer (score 2):

**Cauchy Shwarz Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^xf'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^2\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1[t\le x]\,f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^2\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&\le\int_0^1\int_0^1[t\le x]^2\,\mathrm{d}t\int_0^1\,f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\int_0^1x\,\mathrm{d}x\int_0^1\,f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\,f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$
$(2)$: apply [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$(3)$: apply [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
$(4)$: $\int_0^1[t\le x]^2\,\mathrm{d}t=x$
$(5)$: $\int_0^1x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac12$

---

**Variational Approach**

Without loss of generality, assume that
$$
\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t=1\tag6
$$
which means that
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_0^1f(t)\,\delta f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag7
\end{align}
$$
We want to minimize $\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t$, so we want
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\delta\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=2\int_0^1f'(t)\,\delta f'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-2\int_0^1f''(t)\,\delta f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag8
\end{align}
$$
To find $f$ that satisfy $(8)$ for all $\delta f$ that satisfy $(7)$, orthogonality implies we need
$$
f''=\lambda f\tag9
$$
Since $f(0)=0$, we have either $f(t)=\sin\left(at\right)$, where $\lambda=-a^2$, or $f(t)=\sinh\left(at\right)$, where $\lambda=a^2$.

For $f(t)=\sin\left(at\right)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}{\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}
&=a^2\frac{2a+\sin(2a)}{2a-\sin(2a)}\\
&\ge a^2\frac{2a-1}{2a+1}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
This has a local maximum of $3$ at $a=0$ and global minima of $\frac{\pi^2}4$ at $a=\pm\frac\pi2$.

For $f(t)=\sinh\left(at\right)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}{\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}
&=a^2\frac{\sinh(2a)+2a}{\sinh(2a)-2a}\\
&\ge a^2\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
This has a global minimum of $3$ at $a=0$.

Thus, the critical function is $f(t)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2t\right)$, for which
$$
\frac{\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}{\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\pi^2}4\tag{12}
$$
Therefore, for a general $f$,
$$
\int_0^1f(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\le\frac4{\pi^2}\int_0^1f'(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{13}
$$
As mentioned in mickep's answer.

Comment: As clarification for anybody who might have trouble following this, the first line is from the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the third line is from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I did not think of using the characteristic function $[t\le x]$